# Using nginx upload module and nginx lua together

Tags: nginx, file-upload, lua, upload

I am using nginx upload module for uplaoding files to server. But I wanted nginx to upload to different paths, not to a path mentioned in **upload_store**.
So I am taking help of nginx-lua module to change the upload_store value on each request like below.

```
location /umtest {
            upload_pass /nginx_response;
            set $upload_store '';
            rewrite_by_lua '
                local header = ngx.req.raw_header()
                ngx.say("type header",header)
                dst_path_dir = ngx.req.get_headers()["Dst-Dir"]
                ngx.say("dst_path_dir",dst_path_dir)
                ngx.var.upload_store = dst_path_dir
                ngx.say("upload store path" ,ngx.var.upload_store)    
             ';
                upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name 
               "$upload_file_name";
                upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type 
                "$upload_content_type";
                upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path 
                "$upload_tmp_path"
                upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
               }
```

Now when I POST to the '/umtest' it will change the upload_store value, but it will not execute the nginx upload direcives (i.e., upload will not happen). When I comment the rewrite_by_lua directive , the upload happens. 
My question is cant we use both at a same time to achieve the purpose?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the `ngx.say` lines?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Lua, an obvious workaround would be to just use that to read the request body and save it as a file:

```lua
-- handle_download.lua
ngx.req.read_body()
local body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
local file = io.open("some_file", 'wb')
file:write(body)
file:close()
```

```
location /umtest {
   content_by_lua_file 'handle_download.lua';
}
```

This just dumps the entire request body into a file. You can also [ngx.req.get_post_args()](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_post_args) if the file to be uploaded is sent as part of a HTML form or you can even use [ngx.req.socket()](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqsocket) and read the data yourself as a stream (useful for very big files)